# Why is this "array" not evaluating as an Array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

I can't seem to figure out why **Version 2** doesn't evaluate as an Array. Syntax?

**Version 1 - evaluates as an Array:**

```
var historyArray = [];
this.saveHistory = function(question, answer){

    historyArray['question'] = historyArray['question'] || [];
    historyArray['question'].push(question);
    historyArray['answer'] = historyArray['answer'] || [];
    historyArray['answer'].push(answer);

    if (historyArray instanceof Array){
        console.log("array");
        console.log(historyArray);
    }else{
        console.log("not array");
    }

};
```

**Version 2 - does not evaluate as an Array:**

```
var historyArray = {history:[]};
this.saveHistory = function(question, answer){

    historyArray.history.push({
        'question'  : question,
        'answer'    : answer
    })

    var historyLogJSON = JSON.stringify(historyArray);

    if (historyArray instanceof Array){
        console.log("array");
        console.log(historyLogJSON);
    }else{
        console.log("not array");
    }

};
```

Comment: Cause you made historyArray an object with {}.....

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance - it would help you to narrow down code for this post to `if ({} instanceof Array){...` (unfortunate side effect is you'd probably not post that as question - but sometimes it is ok to not post on SO)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 2, the very first line sets historyArray up using {} - this creates an object, not an array.